# Run python and php in a single heroku app procfile

Tags: php, python, heroku

I haven't been able to find a way to launch two web workers for separate language types in a single Heroku app.

I have a python app running well, and I've added a PHP app in a folder, so my procfile ideally would look something like this:

web:    python pythonapp.py
web:    sh phpapp/index.php

Of course this doesn't work, in fact even if I remove the python worker altogether I can't get the PHP app to run via procfile. The logs just show that it's crashed and "Syntax error: "(" unexpected"

If I just load the PHP app into a Heroku app without a procfile, it runs fine.

So the question is: How to initiate a PHP app via the procfile rather than relying on Heroku to autodetect PHP?

Thanks,

-James

Comment: Might be better off just splitting them into two separate Heroku apps.

Comment: That's how I have it running now, but I was concerned about cross-domain code interaction limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like these applications should be split into two separate codebases.

However, you can achieve this with the multi-buildpack:

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who ends up here years after the thread was started (2020 for me), Heroku now has builtin multi buildpacks.  Use this link for info and how to setup:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

(Note: I got this link by starting with Kenneth Reitz's answer above).